# C program value changing from 1 to 2 characters

Tags: c

I have inherited a C program and I have very limited C experience.
This is the code that is currently there:

```
char *ptr ;
if (data == 0)  /* Buffer not acquired */
  data = (char *)getmem(65535);
ptr = data;  /* create data record */
*ptr = '9';
```

Later in this process it dumps this information to a text file.

I need the data to show double 9's.

```
char *ptr ;
if (data == 0)  /* Buffer not acquired */
  data = (char *)getmem(65535);
ptr = data;  /* create data record */
*ptr = '99';
```

When this outputs the info it still only shows one 9.  Am I not doing the memory allocation correctly?

Comment: Your compiler did *not* warn you about `'99'` not being a standard character? If not, seriously turn up your warning levels.

Comment: how about `strcpy(ptr, "99");` which would also put a null char after the two 9s

Comment: why not use `int* ptr`

Comment: `*ptr = '9'; *(ptr+1) = '9';`

Comment: @WhozCraig I've never had such code even compile before

Comment: @WhozCraig: It is a valid multi-character integer constant. Problem is the layout of the resulting `int` is implementation-specific.

Comment: See [ask], provide a [mcve]. `getmem` is not a standard function.

Comment: @Olaf indeed it is, but if you're not building for mbcs, the proper warning should be turned on. I know when building in Xcode (clang) non mbcs, that warning is up by default.

Comment: @WhozCraig: What is "mbcs"? And why should there be a warning about the integer constant? There might (and should) be a conversion warning (`-Wconversion`) for assigning an `int` to a `char`, but that's unrelated.

Comment: @WhozCraig To be fair, turning up warning level on an old, inherited codebase can be... less than helpful, especially for less experienced C programmers.

Comment: @Olaf the exact warning given by clang is: "main.cpp:113:15: Multi-character character constant", it isn't flagged by -Wconversion (on my chain, anyway). There is a specific setting for that specific warning. Maybe an apple-contrived thing (they do that sometimes with their clang distros).

Comment: @hyde: It will mess things up first, but imo it is a good traning and a good way to enhance code quality in the mid-term. Translating bugged code with a modern compiler without fixing UB, etc. otoh can mess up things way worse.

Comment: @Olaf true that, man. true that.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Can you provide the exact option? I'll check with gcc. I always try to have as much warnings enables are reasonable (which means allways all).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Ok, found it: `-Wno-multichar` disables it, the default already is to warn. Heck, I like gcc (if I used clang, I might also like it:-)

Comment: @Olaf you beat me to the punch. The number of options passed to the build on Xcode (once you remember how to expand them) is pretty breathtaking. Thanks for finding it.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I'm still not sure what "mbcs" means. "Multi-Byte-Character-Sequence"?

Comment: @Olaf multibyte character services. (some people use "system" for 's'). Older Xcode allowed you to turn it on or off, though I can't seem to find it in the latest release I'm running now (7.2.1). Windows *still* has it as an option (though no one in their right mind uses it anymore)

Comment: @WhozCraig: I don't use either. But I have a faint memory old MacOS used 4-character sequences to identify file-resources by using a 32 bit comparison. But those were the 68k and early PPC days :-)

Comment: @Olaf Funny you should mention that. That is *still* a configurable warning, `-Wno-four-char-constants` lolz.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Interestingly not for gcc. Maybe that's indeed something Apple-specific addition (too lazy now to check for vanilla clang).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not being doing multi-character in a single quotes. If you want double 99, at ptr, you should do:

```
*ptr = '9';
*(ptr+1) = '9';
```

Comment: I'm running this in Visual Studio 2012.  I tried strcpy and sramij suggestions and it still only shows 9.  If I add ptr += 1; after sramij suggestion works.  Is there no way to do 2 9's together?

Comment: @JerryWarra by direct assignment, no. Not portably, anyway. You *could* `*ptr = *(ptr+1) = '9';`, I suppose. And of course, don't forget to terminate.

Comment: @JerryWarra, be aware that the `strcpy()` suggestion (i.e. `strcpy(ptr, "99")`) is not exactly equivalent to the pair of single-character assignments, because it will also write a string terminator.  That may or may not be harmless.

Answer (score 2):

The code

> ```
> char *ptr ;
> ```

declares that the expression `*ptr` has type `char`, or, equivalently, that `ptr` is a pointer to a `char` (and therefore has type `char *`).  If you assign a value to the `char` designated by `*ptr` then you set *one* char, because that's what the left-hand side of the assignment represents.

The integer character constant `'9'` corresponds to the character representing the decimal digit `9`.  The integer character constant `'99'` is also valid, but its meaning is implementation-defined.  Your particular implementation evidently defines it such that the result of converting it to type `char` is the same as the result of converting `'9'` to type `char`.  No matter how it was defined, however, assigning it to `*ptr` will modify only the one `char` to which `ptr` directly points, not any other.

The simplest way to set the values of the `char` to which `ptr` points and the next one is that suggested by @EugeneSh., and also by another answer:

```
*ptr = '9'; *(ptr+1) = '9';
```

There are other conforming alternatives, but you have not presented anything giving me reason to think that one of the alternatives would preferable.

Comment: Thank you John for explaining it.  That makes more sense to me now.  Thanks to everyone for your help.